# High-order recursive macro to define several similar macro at once does infinite loop

Tags: macros, programming, recursion

I’m a fan of factorization and hate code repetition. So I was trying to define a macro which defines for me all the common mathematical sets commands (`\C`, `\N`, etc.) and made a recursive function inspiring of `\slowRomannumeral` p. 24 from these [TeX and LaTeX programmation notes](http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/introtex.pdf).

So I did this first:

```
\def\defsets#1{\defnextset #1@}
\def\defnextset#1{\ifx @#1 \else
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\mathbb{#1}}
    \expandafter\defnextset
  \fi}
\defsets{RDNZQC}
```

But I soon realised that I needed something alike for my math operators, exactly the same but just with `\DeclareMathOperator` instead of `\newcommand` and without `\mathbb`, so I defined a `\defset` command and tried to make my main macro high-order:

```
\newcommand{\defset}[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\mathbb{#1}}}
\def\defsets#1{\defnext\defset #1@}
\def\defnext#1#2{\ifx @#2 \else
    #1#2\relax
    \expandafter\defnext#1
  \fi}
\defsets{RDNZQC}
```

And I checked a lot of things: I put a `\relax` otherwise for an unkown reason it tries to redefine expandafter, the first `\newcommand` *does* work, `#1#2` should work, and using `\def` instead of `\newcommand*` to define `\defset` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.68 \defsets{RDNZQC}
```

and adding an `\expandafter` makes the same as the actual current code with `\newcommand*` (and all the same combinations with it): an infinite loop.

So how to make this code work? so I can just make a `\defop` and do the same thing for my math operators and some code tricks with each operator command between braces (since this currently works for single characters actually).

Comment: in your second fragment did you mean `\defnextset` to be `\defnext` (which is used but not defined)

Comment: I corrected that before to see your comment sorry ^^" some mistakes after first question submission.

Comment: I also updated the title (the error was not this one finally)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot skip more than one token by one `\expandafter`. There are more solutions of your problem. For example, you can set the used def-method by `\let` first:

```
\def\defset#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\mathbb{#1}}}

\def\defsets#1{\let\defnextA=\defset \defnext #1@}
\def\defnext#1{\ifx @#1\else
    \defnextA{#1}%
    \expandafter\defnext
  \fi}

\defsets{RDNZQC}
```

Second: you can repeat the def-method as `#1` but with one more `\expandafter`:

```
\def\defset#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{\mathbb{#1}}}

\def\defsets#1{\defnext\defset #1@}
\def\defnext#1#2{\ifx @#2\else
    #1{#2}%
    \expandafter\defnext\expandafter#1%
  \fi}

\defsets{RDNZQC}
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to expand away the `\fi`

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\defset}[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{\mathbb{#1}}}
\def\defsets#1{\defnext\defset #1@}
\def\defnext#1#2{\ifx @#2%
    \expandafter\@gobble
   \else
    #1{#2}%
    \expandafter\@firstofone
   \fi    
    {\defnext#1}}
\defsets{RDNZQ{Zzz}C}


\show\Z
\show\Zzz


\newcommand*{\defop}[1]{\expandafter\DeclareMathOperator\csname #1\endcsname{#1}}

\defnext\defop {Vect}{Spec}@

{\let\protect\show\Vect}

\stop
```

Produces

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
> \Z=\long macro:
->\mathbb {Z}.
l.15 \show\Z

? 
> \Zzz=\long macro:
->\mathbb {Zzz}.
l.16 \show\Zzz

? 
> \Vect =\long macro:
->\qopname \newmcodes@ o{Vect}.
\Vect ->\protect \Vect  

l.23 {\let\protect\show\Vect
                            }
?
```

Note you need to re-brace `#2` as `{#2}` to support multiple token arguments.

Comment: @galex-713 works for me, I updated with your mathoperator example.

Comment: Yes I just noticed what you said on rebracing `#2` and I deleted my comment and accepted your answer.

Comment: @galex-713 I saw  the tick flash to wipet and back:-) oh no, and back again:(

Comment: Well I was going to ask him to add some of your changes like the `\show` and above all the rebracing of `#2` before then noticed he did integrate them without highlighting them.

Comment: @galex-713 I'll probably to survive without your 15 points:-)

Comment: You still got more points than the selected answer :p ;)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is of course in `\expandafter\defnext#1` that tries to expand whatever is replaced for `#1` instead of the intended `\fi`.

If you hate code repetition, you'll surely like this, where `\defsets` and `\defops` are basically one-liners.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defsets}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { ##1 } { \mathbb{##1} }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\defops}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } 
   {
    \galex_declaremathoperator:cn { ##1 } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \galex_declaremathoperator:Nn \DeclareMathOperator
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \galex_declaremathoperator:Nn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defsets{RDNZQC}
\defops{Vect,Spec}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\R}

\texttt{\meaning\Q}

\texttt{\meaning\Spec}

\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname Spec \endcsname}

\end{document}
```

Only one `\expandafter` to show that `\Spec` does the right thing. None in the coding part.

I could have used

```
\exp_args:Nc \DeclareMathOperator { ##1 } { ##1 }
```

instead of defining `\galex_declaremathoperator:Nn` and a variant thereof. But this way all is cleaner and in line with recommendations.

[image]

The same is obtained with `\@tfor`:

```
\makeatletter
%\let\@xp\expandafter % already done by amsmath
\newcommand{\defsets}[1]{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
    \@xp\newcommand\csname\next\@xp\endcsname\@xp{\@xp\mathbb\@xp{\next}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\defops}[1]{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
    \@xp\DeclareMathOperator\csname\next\@xp\endcsname\@xp{\next}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\defsets{RDNZQC}
\defops{{Vect}{Spec}}
```

The `\@tfor` function is essentially the abstract version of the `\slowRomannumeral` trick in your variant: it consumes one item at a time from the token list passed between `:=` and `\do`, doing `\def\next{<item>}` (`\next` can be any token). The main difference is exactly this: we need to expand `\next` if we don't want that it is incorporated in the definition of `\N` and so on. Therefore the long chain of `\expandafter`'s is needed. An *item* in this context is a single token or a braced group.

The `\tl_map_inline:nn` method is *much* better, because the current item is available “literally” as `#1` (so in the body of a definition it must be called `##1`).

Comment: Omg I really need to learn to use this xparse and to become used of it… each time I see it it seems to me so verbose! kinda like Java… That seems a whole language on the top of TeX! is that already used in some packages? or internally within LaTeX?

Comment: @galex-713 It is used in several packages.

Comment: 8 hours ago when I answered I nearly put a comment starting a countdown to a map_inline answer from you:-)

Comment: Oh that’s interesting! I didn’t know about @tfor yet ^^" (I’ll be reading its source to try to understand it soon ^^), but well, I didn’t end your book yet ^^ but why all those `\expandafter` near the end of the line? (how can work the third-last and last while there’s no “second token” after it except the closing brace? and I’m working on how to make the `\mathbb` optionnal if no optional argument is given

Comment: @galex-713 Actually, there should be a `\defops` macro, I'll add it.

Comment: Yet I don’t understand the usage of the `\expandafter` when they are followed by closing-braces: what is it expanding first? How does that work? because I’m trying to make one function with both usages, as you did first with an optional argument ^^

Comment: @galex-713 It jumps over the next token (in this case the brace) and expands the following one.

Comment: yes but *what is* the following one? there’s nothing after `\@xp{\next}`, just closing braces.

Comment: @galex-713 The following *token*, not group. So `\expandafter{\next}` expands `\next` before the `{` has its effect.

Comment: @galex-713 `\@for` and `\@tfor` are ***very*** different

Comment: Oh ok for expansion… I guess… yet I have to find how to put a conditional in there… But what is the problem of `\@for`? can’t it be used for `\defops` in order to parse the csv?

Answer (score 3):

Seems I wake up after the battle, all dust has settled ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xinttools}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\defsets [1]
   {\xintFor* ##1 in {#1} \do {\@namedef{##1}{\mathbb{##1}}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\defops [1]
   {\xintFor ##1 in {#1} \do {\expandafter
           \DeclareMathOperator\csname ##1\endcsname{##1}}}


\defsets{RDNZQC}
\defops{Vect, Spec}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\R}

\texttt{\meaning\Q}

\texttt{\meaning\Spec}

\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname Spec \endcsname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t like the use of external packages :/ except over-used packages like ams’s one and maybe `xparse` when I’ll able to understand it. :/

Comment: you mean `xinttools` isn't an _over-used package_ ?!?! that's shocking ! egreg himself says having the item "literally as `#1`" was (quote) _much_ better ;-) Have you looked at `TeX by Topic`?

Comment: I didn’t know about it sorry (is it used in a lot of packages too so?), I just learned about xparse not so long ago… and I think I’ve understood xparse is more used/more general than xinttools… Yet I like to being able to understand how does works what I’m using so I’m planning to study xparse before, and if you think it’s worth maybe xinttools too. (Oh and I just noticed about `\@namedef`! Interesting too! is there some version of it with `\newcommand`/`\*newcommand`?). Btw, what’s `TeX by Topic`?

Comment: @galex-713 I was just making a little joke, as xinttools is my own package ;-) naturally great package xparse is much more used, in relation to the whole of  `expl3`, programming layer of future LaTeX3. In contrast xinttools provides some random utilities à la Plain TeX, which were useful for me in other contexts. TeX by Topic is a well-known reference book for people who want to master TeX language; complementary to TeXBook. Reading it is good way to master the basics, so that you then understand what LaTeX3 is built upon, even if ultimately it will hide all of those roots.

Comment: Oh great! I read TeXBook long time ago (need to re-read it again, I’ll probably understand more of it this time ^^), and even if I forgot a bit I still wasn’t able to understand all the TeX/LaTeX core ^^ I began TeX for the impatient as well as the egreg’s book for that but one more book won’t be too much :D Oh and that’s great I didn’t know LaTeX3 was going to build on `xparse` (or maybe did I read it only once somewhere I forgot…), I just got repelled by the syntax that was like seeming inconsistent with the rest of (La)TeX and remembered me some horrible javascript framework…

Comment: @galex-713 I suspect one shouldn't say 'LaTeX3 is going to build on xparse', but from what I gather, presumably much of the syntax of `xparse` for the end-user will indeed be part of what LaTeX3 will offer. Please people correct me here if needed. (it is actually `xparse` which is built upon future LaTeX3 in a way)

Comment: @galex-713 the `xparse` syntax looks indeed different with the rest of legacy LaTeX, but it has strong justifications. Obviously, `xparse` is very powerful package and I think its facilities will be part of how LaTeX3 will do things for the end users. It greatly facilitates things for package authors as well who won't have to re-invent the wheel each time.